Non-commutative banach algebra
A theorem states that if $A$ is a commutative Banach algebra, then for all $a\in A$
we have
$$\sigma(a)=\{\chi(a) : \chi \text{ is a character }\}$$
My question what if $A$ is not commutative. Does the theorem still hold.

Characters are usually defined only for commutative algebras, so the RHS does not make sense in the general non commutative setting. This question might interest you as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067788/is-phi-a-meaningful-for-a-non-commutative-banach-algebra-a

@AlonsoDelfin There is no technical problem with defining characters in the non commutative case, they just don't have the same nice properties that they have in the commutative case. They might not even exist.

@Mark yes you're right. I guess Qiaochu Yuan answers puts this to rest though.

In the noncommutative case it can happen that $A$ has no characters at all. This happens iff its abelianization is zero, and easy examples are given by $A = M_n(\mathbb{C}), n \ge 2$. So typically we only talk about characters in the commutative case.
In a positive direction you can instead consider the Banach subalgebra generated by $a$, which is commutative, and characters on that subalgebra.

A technical point worth pointing out: the spectrum of $a$ in $A$ and the spectrum of $a$ in the Banach algebra generated by $a$ may not be the same. For example, the bilateral shift $u$ on $l^2$ has spectrum $\mathbb{T}$ as an operator in $B(l^2)$ (or in $C^\ast(u)$), but has spectrum $\mathbb{D}$ in the Banach algebra generated by $u$. So $\chi(a)$ where $\chi$ ranges over characters on the Banach algebra generated by $a$ gives the spectrum of $a$ in the Banach algebra generated by $a$, but not necessarily in the original algebra $A$.

@David: ah, thanks, I wasn't familiar with this. If $a$ is a normal element of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra they should be the same, yes? That's the case I'm more familiar with.

No, not really. $u$, as above, is a unitary and thus normal, but the spectra are still not the same. If $a$ is a normal element in a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$, then the spectrum of $a$ in $A$ is the same as the spectrum of $a$ in the $C^\ast$-algebra generated by $a$, but not necessarily the Banach algebra generated by $a$.

Sorry, yes, that's what I meant (working with the $C^{\ast}$-algebra generated by $a$).
